# Is it okay to boldify(higlight) the portion of answer that is deserved to be, without posters permission?

Tags: discussion, editing

Please consider [this](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/30012/do-researchers-generally-treat-tensors-just-as-mathematical-objects-with-certain) question for better understanding the question as this doubt originated while going through the question.

The core part of the question is **How do researchers generally treat tensors?**

For this question, I think, it is better if I modify a certain portion of the answer as follows

> I would say they are treated as **multidimensional arrays of
> numbers**. They are not visualized in their actual dimension.
> Sometimes small ones will be visualized when someone is trying to
> explain a concept that requires it.

I just boldified the relevant part of the answer that needs attention.

Is such activity recommended without the knowledge of the actual poster?

Comment: Regarding "without the knowledge of the actual poster", original posters are notified on the site when someone edits one of their questions or answers. That doesn't answer whether or not this kind of edit is a good idea.

Answer (score 6):

I generally agree with Neil's suggestions.

I would also like to emphasize that making or not a word or sentence bold is sometimes a

- **matter of style** and
- it **depends on what the OP or you want to emphasize** (you see, here, **I think** that these two points are particularly important, so I made them bold).

The problem is that what you want to emphasize might not be what the OP thinks is really important. Maybe you're just not familiar with a concept and you think that a word needs to be emphasized, while, in reality, it's not really that important (for the OP, at least).

Having said that, I think that, especially **when an answer is long** and there are no subsections, titles, etc, but it's just plain text, it may be a good idea to edit the post to structure it in a way to emphasize the main points (which might also include making the most important words or parts of the answer in bold or maybe just italic). This would fall into the category of "improving the clarity/presentation of the post." If an answer contains only 2-3 lines, that might not be necessary. So, as a rule of thumb, I would say that the longer the answer the more necessary emphasis might be. But keep in mind that, if you make everything bold, that would have the opposite effect of what you originally wanted.

As the person with the highest number of edits on this site, I can say that I've edited posts for multiple reasons, including the ones mentioned in Neil's answers (and I've edited several of his answers for those same purposes). Sometimes, I've edited posts and the OP didn't like my edits. I would say that my edits usually improve the post (although, especially in the past, that might not always have been the case) and there are some stubborn users that don't really want their posts to be touched. In that case, it may be a good reason to flag the issue to a moderator or let the user know that, [if they are not comfortable with their posts being edited, maybe this site is not for them](https://ai.stackexchange.com/help/editing). **You can and should edit posts to improve the clarity, but the boundary between clarity and style is not always clear**. For example, I noticed that some users like to make certain parts of his answers bold or maybe use sections and bullets, while others don't really care about that and don't even use paragraphs and spaces (but sometimes that might just be because they didn't have the time or will to spend 1 hour to write a beautiful answer, so it might still be a good idea to edit those posts to improve their clarity!).

My final suggestions about your specific question are:

1. if you really think something needs to be made bold (because the answer is plain text and not easy to understand the key takeaways), then edit it, make it bold, or change the structure.
2. If the OP rolls back your edit, then just don't start an edit war, i.e. don't edit again, and maybe leave a comment explaining why you think that your edit was opportune, and/or flag the answer for a moderator to intervene
3. If you think that you would need to change many things in an answer to make it readable or valuable, just downvote. Don't lose your time with those answers.

Answer (score 4):

Everyone will have slightly different boundaries on what feels ok as edits to their original content. I'm usually fine with typo and layout corrections. Most of the edits I see are due to someone editing the question for typos or clarity, then editing my answer where it quotes the old version of the question. But I do also make plenty of typos myself, and appreciate it when someone finds and corrects one.

The more subjective an edit is, the more it deserves an attempt at conversation first. Obvious typos and mistakes don't need any extra conversation, it is even wasteful of OP and editor's time. However, emphasis can subtly change the meaning of text, so is worth a second or so of thought, and maybe communication.

I would say in this case, an edit to bold or otherwise emphasise a key phrase *done directly* could go too far. Although I would say that for me this is a small issue of politeness, and I would not be motivated to complain or do anything about it. As the OP, I get notified of edits, so if I felt the highlighting was not appropriate it is easy to roll back. If I was repsonsible for your example answer, I'd probably just leave your edit in place.

As an original poster I would prefer if possible a comment with the suggestion to highlight the key phrase, or better still a statement about what is hard to read or understand about the answer, so I can decide on a suitable edit - it may not need to be highlighting.

The following things make it OK (in my opinion) to directly edit to make this kind of improvement without discussion:

- The rest of the answer already uses bold highlighting for key phrases, and the one you want to highlight is an obvious candidate.
- You are already making other edits for layout and clarity, and the highlighting is one small extra.
- The answer is old, the original poster is not available, or has made the answer a community wiki.